# How to get names from list when it keeps returning null?

Tags: r, statistics

For my coding class, my professor wants us to list the variables (vectors) of a .json list file that he had us download. When we've previously used lists and named them, I was able to use name(df) to get the names of the variables, but when I run names(df) for this dataset, it just returns null. How can I get the names of the variables?
My code:

```r
library(jsonlite)
json <- read_json("Data/hw4twitter.json") #Name of our file
names(json) #Returns null
```

When I use head(json) to read the lists, I can see the variables, but I don't know what sort of code to use to run a function that would list the variables. The file is filled with tweets and metadata.

Comment: Can you show the output of `head(json)`?

Comment: `[[1]]
[[1]]$id
[1] "1351055834743255043"

[[1]]$public_metrics
[[1]]$public_metrics$retweet_count
[1] 1784

[[1]]$public_metrics$reply_count
[1] 0

[[1]]$public_metrics$like_count
[1] 0

[[1]]$public_metrics$quote_count
[1] 0


[[1]]$created_at
[1] "2021-01-18T06:36:27.000Z"

[[1]]$entities
[[1]]$entities$mentions
[[1]]$entities$mentions[[1]]
[[1]]$entities$mentions[[1]]$start
[1] 3

[[1]]$entities$mentions[[1]]$end
[1] 15

[[1]]$entities$mentions[[1]]$username
[1] "Amy_Siskind"




[[1]]$author_id
[1] "846127897706446848"`

Comment: I only did it for 1 value though because it was too long

Comment: Not sure what your professor wants. Perhaps `names(rapply(json, names, "list", NA))`